Need to Read a file from SFTP endpoint with Proxy enabled in apache camel
I need to read a file from sftp server which is proxy enabled. How to build endpoint for apache camel route with spring boot to consume a file from the sftp folder. Without proxy, i am able to read it from one channel. With proxy enabled for the sftp channel, the spring boot application itself is not starting. I am using apache camel version 4.16.0. Please help me with the syntax how to achieve it.?
sftp://\<sftp_username\>@\<sftp_host\>:\<sftp_port\>\<root_folder\>?delay=5000&delete=true&include=.\*%5C.json&noop=false&password=xxxxxx&proxy=true&proxyHost=\<proxy_host\>&proxyPort=\<proxy_port\>&readLock=rename

Getting the below error:

... 29 common frames omitted Caused by:
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException:
org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException: No type converter
available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the required type:
com.jcraft.jsch.Proxy

Trying to read a file but getting an error when starting the application.

The camel documentation doesn't say anything about the proxyHost and proxyPort query parameters. You need to use the parameter proxy, but this is not a boolean, but an implementation of type com.jcraft.jsch.Proxy. For example, if you want to use a Http proxy, you can create a bean like this:
Proxy myProxy = new ProxyHTTP("localhost", 8080);

You need to then pass this object as a reference to your route, indicated by the #:
sftp://\<sftp_username\>@\<sftp_host\>:\<sftp_port\>\<root_folder\>?delay=5000&delete=true&include=.\*%5C.json&noop=false&password=xxxxxx&proxy=#myProxy&readLock=rename

https://camel.apache.org/components/4.4.x/sftp-component.html

Great.. Thanks.. Only change is that spring context expects the proxy object to be defined as bean.. After doing it, it works.. Thanks again..
